# docker username interactive result in "i have no name" error?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to do an interactive session with a specific username and password.

```
docker run -it --rm --user 616:605 -e USER=penny \
-v /Y/penny/resource:/penny/
e5542f8d0cf8 bash
```

the command above results in a prompt

```
I have no name!@2bed4cfb594g:/$
```

What I want is to have the username with the group gid correctly login so that I can read/write files with the correct permissions.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the /etc/passwd file in your container has no entry for the username for the UID:GID 616:605.

If you run the id command inside your container, you will get the UID. Now copy the /etc/passwd file from  your container and add the name to the UID.

```
# copy file to the host file system at /tmp
docker cp e5542f8d0cf8:/etc/passwd /tmp 
# Append (not overwrite) to the file 
echo "username:x:616:605:username:/tmp:/bin/bash" >> /tmp/passwd   
# copy the file from the host to the container
docker cp /tmp/passwd e5542f8d0cf8:/etc/passwd
```

Now login to the container again and you should see the username